# Linking to specific answers or comments

Tags: support, comments, answers, hyperlinks

How do I give someone a link to a specific answer or comment? I know I can, but the only way I can do it now is to go to my user's recent activity and grab the link from there.

Is there an easier way? Or a formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link to an answer, click the link link just under and towards the left of the answer text. (h/t msh210 [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/572/759))

To link to a comment, right click and save the link of the timestamp next to a comment. This is a relatively new SE feature. (h/t IsaacMoses [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/571/linking-to-specific-answers-or-comments/768#comment1648_768) for the link to [this recent post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120688/179) on meta.SO)

Comment: Can anyone confirm? Is this a permanent solution?

Comment: Nice discovery! I had no idea. It does work for me as well, FTR.

Comment: There's a [new answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120688/179) to the question you previously [linked](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/573/2) documenting this as a new feature as of Jan. 30, 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Answers are easy: each answer has a "link" link beneath it, whose URL is the answer's. (See just below.)

For comments, the only way I know of (besides what you mentioned) is to check the HTML source code, but perhaps someone else can answer better.

Comment: Ahh I missed that! I don't see anything like that by the comments though...

Comment: Right, there's nothing like that for comments AFAIK. Checking the HTML source code will show something like `<tr class="comment" id="comment-1287">` before a comment; `#comment-1287` after the URL (e.g. [http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/571/linking-to-specific-answers-or-comments/572#comment-1287](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/571/linking-to-specific-answers-or-comments/572#comment-1287)) will do it, then.

Comment: But, according to Shog9's answer to the question DoubleAA's answer here links to, that's not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I wasn't the first to think of this. See: [meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5436/166155)